# Как передать значения input в JS при нажатии на него?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Новичок в этом плане, многих тонкостей не знаю. В C# в общем то, в таблице можно было вытаскивать значения на прямую. Одной строчкой кода. А конкретно в веб-разработке я такого не нашел. Поэтому нужна помощь.

Вопрос следующий:

Как передать значение input в js при нажатии на него?

Вся проблема в том, что в input поступает массив данных, полученный с history.php , в котором был запрос к БД. В целом, если поменять атрибут на submit можно увидеть в строке браузера нужное значение: inf=2. Возможно его как то можно вытащить?

**Код главной страницы wow.php:**

```
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                         <th></th>
                         <th>Дата создания</th>
                         <th>Статус</th>
                         <th>Дата готовности</th>
                         <th>Мастер</th>
                         <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input name= "inf" id = "inf"type="text" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"/>
                                <td><?php echo $row['DateVisit']; ?>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Done']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['DateReady']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php 
                                echo $row['SurName'];
                                echo $row['Name'];
                                echo $row['Patronymic'];?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <button class= "btn" type="button" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">Подробнее</button >
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

И если же попробовать данным способом, то он выведет лишь только [object Object]. Также пробовал и по другому решить через `'btn'.value`- но в таком случае выведет первое значение (1). Оно и понятно поступает массив.

**Код history.js:**

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
        let request ={
            'id_h':$('input[name="inf"]').val()
        };
        alert(request);
        });
```

И для наглядности таблица, пока без стилей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь на помощь. А то уже не знаю, что делать(

Comment: `inf` у  Вас в `input` элементе поэтому вытягивать его из `btn` (как я понимаю кнопки)  не вижу никакого смысла. Тут важно решить когда вам нужно получить это значение? К примеру при получении фокуса тогда `$('input').on('focus',` и далеее уже через `this.val()` можно достать, хотя я бы тут вообще не использовал `JQuery` но если он итак есть то можно и его использовать.

Comment: Чтобы распечатать или вывести объект в js используйте `JSON.stringify(объект)` тогда не будете видеть  `[object Object]` — строка по умолчанию для любого объекта

Comment: @DaniilLoban спасибо большое за эту информацию! Все работает, столько всего перерыл, а решение оказалось простым. Надо будет подтягивать знания.